# NavigationStack is cleared after Popasync

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a weird behavior on Xamarin.Forms on iOS. Before popping, I have 3 pages in my navigation stack. After popping, the navigation stack is empty.

In this screenshot, you can see that my navigation stack has 3 items.
[image: Before popping a page]

Now, my navigation stack is empty
[image: After popping a page]

How can I solve/workaround this?
Thanks!

Comment: If you've evaluated `await Navigation.PopAsync()` twice will debugging then it would happen. It's easy to disturb your program's execution in debug without thinking about it.

Comment: I'm just watching the Navigation.NavigationStack count

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue where calling Navigation.PopAsync clears the entire stack the first time its called. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I store my view in a variable before I pop anything